# What is distinctive purpose of API Blueprint vs Swagger?

Tags: rest, swagger, apiblueprint

I am trying to develop application in cloud native way. I am trying have API first design of my application.

Which API documentation tool should I use? which one is more suitable for API first Contracts? rather which one of it suitable where?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd say both formats are suitable for API first approach, so it's a matter of taste (markdown vs yaml/json based) or tool limitation.

You can read a brief summary at https://help.apiary.io/api_101/choosing-format/.

> Both formats are open-sourced and have great community and tooling
>   built around them.
>
> - Swagger is YAML (or JSON) format, with focus to be easy to parse and
>     has wide options of extensions and integrations.
> - API Blueprint comes
>     with syntax close to Markdown, MSON and full support of all Apiary
>     tooling and open-source tooling.
>
> Both should allow you to describe a
>   broad set of API architectures with design-first approach. Swagger
>   comes with tools to generate a description from code. API Blueprint
>   syntax makes it easier to describe hypermedia/REST APIs.
>
> If you are new to API Description world, we recommend to start with
>   API Blueprint.